# Aria2c as daemon on Debian

Tags: debian, download-manager

How can I run aria2c as a daemon on a Debian machine?

The idea is:

Run aria2c on Debian NAS + aria2 client on windows machine, to manage on download jobs...

Answer (score 2):

You can use aria2c as a daemon with

```
aria2c -D
```

Comment: But then how do you interact with the daemon from a distant machine (windows in this case)? Well, I'm currently writing aria2p for this purpose: https://github.com/pawamoy/aria2p. It's a work-in-progress, watch the repo to see how it goes!